# public folder on redmine doesn't recognize binary files

Tags: ruby, redmine, webrick

I have put a binary file (.apk) on redmine/public folder but when I try to download that file I only get the text version of that file as text.

How to change that behavior to direct download?

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to the `httputils.rb` file (it's wherever webrick is installed) and add this line to the list of MIME types:

```
application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk
```

If that seems like a lot of trouble and you're not trying to do anything fancy with this download (e.g. download it directly from an android phone and install it), you can always wrap it in a `.zip` and call it a day. Zip files will download automatically.

Comment: There is no httputils.rb file in redmine source code

Comment: @IvanCachicatari are you sure you're using webrick to power redmine then? if you're using webrick, there's an httputils.rb *somewhere*.

Comment: I found that file, but still doesn't work... when I try to load the apk: `curl -s -D - http://localhost:3000/app.apk -o /dev/null` I got `Content-Type: text/html`